# Official AOM documentation

Tags: ffmpeg

I could not find the official description for AOM encoding options. There are some documentations available online. However I get following contradicting explanations for aq-mode. can someone help me with the correct documentation?

https://api.encoding.com/reference/adv-av1-libaom says the default value for aq-mode is 0 and "ffmpeg -h encoder=libaom-av1" gives default value = -1.

Comment: `-1` here means ffmpeg will leave it up to the encoder.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a link available for libaom-av1 official documentation.

Comment: See https://aomedia.org/docs/aomenc-command-line-parameters-draft.pdf and https://github.com/master-of-zen/Av1an/blob/master/docs/Encoders/aomenc.md#Important-command-line-options